# Excel spreadsheet sometimes fails to start from Startup folder shortcut

Tags: excel, vba, startup

On a Windows 7 box, I have an Excel spreadsheet with a shortcut in the Startup folder. Usually it starts up correctly when Windows starts up, but often enough to be annoying all that happens is that only Excel starts; no spreadsheet. I'd say about one time in ten. The spreadsheet has startup (and other) VBA code and  Any bright ideas?

I had been thinking maybe an insufficiently specific object reference in the startup code was the issue, and yesterday I found and fixed one. But this morning I had the issue again with only Excel starting! Logically, I don't think it can be anything to do with my code anyway, because there's no sign that it ever gets processed!

Comment: Maybe sometimes you have  Disable all macros without notification in the Trust Center.

Comment: Hi Black cat, That's an interesting suggestion ... but why might that setting be volatile? It's certainly not something I'm trying to manipulate with VBA in any of my spreadsheet apps - that's well beyond my "knows enough to be dangerous" capability. I just opened up a blank workbook in Excel to see how that setting was set, and it was set to "Enable all macros" which is what I want. What could cause it to be changed?

Comment: In TrustCenter Settings turn on the Show Message Bar option to show blocked infos. Be sure that if nothing changed the result is the same.  Do you save the workbook after it is opened, or only close?

Comment: 1) Good point! Show Message Bar option was already turned on. I never get any notification or error message when Excel opens up blank instead of opening the required spreadsheet. But I guess I can only conclude that Excel is never getting as far as trying to open the spreadsheet if that Show Message Bar setting isn't somehow changing behind the scenes. 2) Unsure what to do to "Be sure that if nothing changed the result is the same." 3) Interested you ask this because I typically save after it is opened, even if I don't change anything. How might this be relevant?

Comment: Pls. Check the Options->Save tab.

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to upload a screenshot? What are we looking for?

Comment: (I ran out of comment edit time :) ... I'm saving as .xlsx; I'm not saving AutoRecover info; I have the option checked to "show additional places for saving, even if sign-in may be required" (I don't know why, it's not something I've checked intentionally); my save checked-out files radio button is set to "The Office Document Cache" (again I don't know why, I haven't fiddled with it. I don't check out files. The path specified is presumably default and I just looked and it doesn't exist). Anything else can I tell you?